# docker stats in Swarm mode?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode, resource-utilization

Im trying to setup docker in swarm mode and monitor the resource utilization of all the services/containers running in the swarm.

Docker stats on the manager node doesnt seem to show the resource utilization on the worker nodes.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at https://grafana.com/dashboards/609?

Comment: Im looking for something like docker stats, through which I can get the utilization easily, like using the api, does grafana expose some api to do this?

Comment: Yes it does, http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/

Comment: that is an api to setup grafana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to retrieve all container stats of a given service in a Swarm. You'll probably have to use more steps to discover all tasks of a service, all node addresses, and each container id. The [engine api docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) should help you getting started. If you need some inspiration, I'd suggest you to peek into such overview dashboards like the https://github.com/charypar/swarm-dashboard or the https://github.com/dockersamples/docker-swarm-visualizer.

Answer (score 4):

Try Ansible:

```
ansible docker -a "docker stats --no-stream"
```

Where you setup your "docker" nodes in `/etc/ansible/hosts`

Comment: exactly the answer the OP was (rightly) looking for; all it requires is ansible on the manager + automated way to log into other docker hosts from manager, which is likely the case anyway; produces `docker stats` output for each of the docker hosts. Cool. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for CPU and Memory usage

```
docker stats --all --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Name}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"
```

Comment: displays stats only for the host, where run; no swarm info

Answer (score 0):

You can use cadvisor to deploy on each node or a swarm service extended on all nodes and collect metrics one by node.

docker run -d --name=cadvisor -p 8080:8080 --volume=/var/run:/var/run:rw --volume=/sys:/sys:ro --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro google/cadvisor:latest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for all worker nodes using the following bash command:

```
docker node ls | grep -v Leader | grep -v Reachable | cut -c 31-47 | grep -v HOSTNAME | xargs -I"SERVER" sh -c "echo SERVER; ssh SERVER docker stats --no-stream"
```

This command works as follows.

List all Docker swarm nodes:

```
docker node ls
```

Filter out the manager nodes:

```
grep -v Leader | grep -v Reachable
```

Select the ip-addresses of the worker nodes:

```
cut -c 31-47
```

Remove the column header from the result:

```
grep -v HOSTNAME
```

Print the ip-address of the worker node and execute docker stats on the worker node:

```
xargs -I"SERVER" sh -c "echo SERVER; ssh SERVER docker stats --no-stream"
```